# Fill bar chart with choosed Color and Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any know how to set the color of the bars? For example, I would to set SO2 in red and NOx in blue.I used the code below :

```
Emission.l <- melt(Emission.Aerosol, id.vars = 'Year', 
                   measure.vars = c('SO2.tons', 'NOx.tons'))

gp <- ggplot(Emission.l, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable))
gp <- gp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
gp <- gp + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', fill=c("red","blue"))
gp <- gp + ggtitle(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name)
gp <- gp + ylab("Emission(Tons)")
gp <- gp + scale_fill_discrete( name = '', 
                                labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'))
gp <- gp + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2015)


ggsave(filename= paste0(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name,".png"),device = "png", 
       width = 15, height = 10,units = "cm", dpi = 100)
```

But get the error message : 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26): fill
Thanks a lot you for help !

Comment: take out the fill from the `geom_bar`. If you want to specify colours do in the `scale_fill_discrete`

Comment: Hi Richard, I deleted `, fill=c("red","blue"` from  the 'geom_bar' and add to 'scale_fill_discrete' as 'gp <- gp + scale_fill_discrete( fill=c('red','blue'),name = '', 
                                labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'))' But it does not work for me

Comment: sorry - change `scale_fill_discrete` to `scale_fill_manual(labels =  c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'), value = c("red", "blue"))`

Comment: I change it to `gp <- gp + scale_fill_manual(labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'), value = c("red", "blue"))` but get the error message: Error in ggproto(NULL, ScaleDiscrete, call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
  argument "values" is missing, with no default

Comment: yes, needs to be `values` rather than `value` (most functions would tolerate this)

Comment: That's totally works, Thank you very much for your guidance, Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee Yee,

Can you give a pointer to the dataset you are using? What is the emissions dataset, can it be accessed online?

In reference to ggplot, read the linked book reference and read section "Modifying the text of legend titles and labels" in

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

See below:

```
  require(ggplot2)
  gp <- ggplot(Emission.l, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable))
  gp <- gp + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
  gp <- gp + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') 
  gp <- gp + ggtitle(Emission.Aerosol$Facility.Name)
  gp <- gp + ylab("Emission(Tons)")
  gp <- gp + scale_fill_manual(labels = c('SO2 (tons)', 'NOx (tons)'), values = c("red", "blue"))
  gp <- gp + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2003:2015)

  powerplant <- gp
  print(powerplant)  
  dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you Pete, that works for me. I always checked the cookbook before asking questions here. But sometimes, the debug is very hard for me who is new to R.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Luis to Richard Telford he nailed it.

Comment: Hi @Pete Jarvis, I have some other related questions would you take a look at ? Thanks a lot !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752276/add-legend-and-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph